# ng-if, else, angular JS not working properly

Tags: angularjs, stringify

just need a quick help in ng-if-else

```
<div ng-if = "{{t.assignee}} != 'A CONTACT NAME'">
     {{t.assignee}}
</div>
```

t.assignee is stored in array. its not working

Comment: <div ng-if = "t.assignee == 'A CONTACT NAME'">
         {{t.assignee}}
 </div>

still not worinf :(

Comment: {{t.assignee | json}} what does this output? Can you try that outside ng-if?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use expression

```
<div ng-if = "t.assignee != 'A CONTACT NAME'">
     {{t.assignee}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) is already in an angular context so you can just do this:

```
<div ng-if = "t.assignee != 'A CONTACT NAME'">
    {{t.assignee}}
</div>
```

No need to use an expression within the directive.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try it this if is not array

```
<div ng-if = "t.assignee !== 'A CONTACT NAME'">
         {{t.assignee}} 
</div>
```